# Show that $(1+x)(1+z) \leq (1-(x+z))^-1$, when x,z > 0 and (x+z) < 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I think my proof is wrong because I don't need the $(x+z) < 1$ in my argumentation.
Can somebody tell me where I made a mistake in my transformations?

$$(1+x)(1+z) \leq (1-(x+z))^{-1}$$ <=>

$$(1-(x+z))(1+x)(1+z) \leq 1$$ <=>

$$(1+x)(1+z) - (x+z)(1+x)(1+z) \leq 1$$ <=>

$$(1+x+z+xz) - (1+x+z+xz)(x+z) \leq 1$$ <=>

$$(1+x+z+xz) - (1+(x+z)+xz)(x+z) \leq 1$$ <=>

$$(1+x+z+xz) - ((1+(x+z)+xz)(x+z)) -1 \leq 0$$ <=>

$$1+(x+z)+xz - ((x+z)(x+z)^2(xz(x+z))) {-1} \leq 0$$ <=>

$$xz - (x+z)^2 - (xz(x+z)) \leq 0$$ <=>

$$xz - x^2 - 2xz - z^2 - (xz(x+z)) \leq 0$$ <=>

$$-xz - x^2 - z^2 - (xz(x+z)) \leq 0$$

This is true because x,z are positive numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Expanding we get
$$-x^2z-xz^2-x^2-z^2-xz+1\le 1$$

Comment: Is my proof wrong or not sufficient?

Comment: No all ok, i have got the same!

Comment: I think there is a little computation error?

Comment: I think it's fixed now.

Comment: I have thought about this inequality again and there is something I don't understand. Since I don't Need the Information that (x+z) < 1, (x+z) has no restriction. But the inequality for x = 3 and z = 4 is obviously false because (1+3)(1+4)≤(1−(3+4)) −1 <=> 20 <= (-6)^-1

Comment: But $$3+4=7>1$$!

Comment: Ok but let's assume we wouldn't know that (x+z) < 1, how could we Show that the inequality only works if this property is given?

Comment: because I made a proof that does not Need the restriction apperantly.

Comment: But you have multiplied by $$1-(x+y)>0$$!

Comment: Got it now, if this would be neagative then the inequality would be false in step 2 and the term is only positive when (x+z) < 1.

Comment: Ok, nice then your Problem is solved now?

Comment: It is, thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I thought about it again and it is still unclear. My question is on which step it is necessary that (x+y) < 1 ? I thought it would be enough to say that if the property is not given (1-(x+y)) would be negative but if the left side at step two is negative it is still smaller than one so it would be no contradiction and thus not necessary. But somewhere it has to be necessary because like I have already said the inequality is wrong for x = 3 and z = 4  because (1+3)(1+4)≤(1−(3+4)) −1 <=> 20 <= (-6)^-1

Comment: it is still the same, when you multiply by $$(1-(x+z))^{-1}$$ it must be positive!

Comment: Ok just to be sure on step 1 we have a positive left side which must be smaller than the right side. That means the right side is also positive, and if (1−(x+z))^-1  must be positive than also (1−(x+z)) and that is where we have to make the restriction that (x+y) < 1. Ok that's it, thank you again for your Patience.